# Passing param to function in ksh script

Tags: unix, ksh

The parameter passed is changed when printed from inside the function

```
print "param: $FILEPREFIX" 1>&2;  #return finyear*
func_copy $FILEPREFIX
```

then in function

```
function func_copy 
{
    fp=$1
    print "param: $fp" 1>&2;  #returns finyear.scr which is a script file name
```

what would i be doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke `func_copy $FILEPREFIX` and `FILEPREFIX` contains `finyear*`, the shell expands the variable and then does wild-card matching, so the name `finyear*` is changed to `finyear.scr` in your directory.  To avoid the expansion, enclose the name in double quotes:

```
func_copy "$FILEPREFIX"
```

(Using double quotes around a variable expansion is usually, but not always, a good idea.)

See the Bash manual on [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) for the sequence of operations in Bash.  The POSIX shell ([`sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html)) has similar rules, and Korn shell will likewise be similar — they all have a common ancestor, the Bourne shell.

Comment: Thanks. * was the problem